# How to trim (crop) canvas colors with ImageMagick similar to Photoshop Trim Canvas?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a series of images that have a lot of white space padding (about 50% of the image).  I need to trim these off such that the image has no border from the actual image to the edge of the image canvas.

This sample:

[image: sample]

Should become this:

[image: result]

Any ideas on how to accomplish this via ImageMagick or even any other purely programatic tool (*no commercial apps allowed*)?  If language specific, would prefer `go` or `ruby` but other answers are acceptable as they can be wrapped in a script and executed.

Comment: Image links are broken for me. What have you tried?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim or this: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#trim (found by typing "rmagick trim" into Google)

Comment: @NeilSlater thanks, yes, I simply missed that it was explaining that and ran into an issue where the images were a little fuzzier and that fuzz option should solve it.

Comment: I'd say that this has nothing to do with go our ruby, thus I'm removing the tags. A solution would be imagemagick specific, and thus should be implementable through any imagemagick api.

Comment: Yeah, I was interested in seeing other options outside of ImageMagick as well @x3ro. As the main script was written in Go, but also had used Ruby to handle a few sub components.